# What resources are required for running a Monero mining pool?

Tags: mining-pool-setup

What are the approximate resource costs of running a Monero mining pool for the following number of users:

10 users

100 users

1000 users

Additionally, it is most efficient to run the mining pool with the Monerodo OS or another service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Overall

The bandwidth usage for running a pool is surprisingly low. Any given month my pool mine.moneroworld.com only has 1-2% utilization of a 2TB allowance. The cost comes in the actual hardware.

> 10's of users

I am currently running mine.moneroworld.com on a 2$ / month VPS with 1 gig of ram and 2 virtual CPUs. (for those that mine there, why do you think the fee is so low? :) ) It can handle "real" users well enough, upwards of 50 miners.

That scale, however, can not handle "fleet" level miners. One miner has access to about 3,000 mining computers and can direct them to a pool all at once. This particular miner can essentially kill my pool.

> For 100's of users

You could probably use a very high end VPS or a cheap dedicated server. (somewhere around 20-30$ / month)

> For 1000's of users

High end dedicated hardware is required (pending any pool efficiency improvements). I've seen the operator of the [mega french pool](http://monero.crypto-pool.fr/) write that the pool uses upwards of 4 servers to distribute the load.

> Caveats

Some of the resource utilization can be modified to increase pool efficiency. For instance, you can change the block template creation rate, because this is CPU intensive. You can also change the share submission time window - each share submission is data over the network. So if you allow a share every 5 seconds, your server needs to be able to handle a share every 5 seconds. And the existing pool code is incredibly inefficient for some tasks.